# How to force pyparsing to parenthesize infix notation "9 + 2 + 3"

Tags: python, pyparsing

Let's take a look at the simplest arithmetic example in the pyparsing doc, [here](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleArith.py).

More specifically, I'm looking at the "+" operation that is defined as left associative and the first example test where we're parsing "9 + 2 + 3".

The outcome of the parsing I would have expected would be ((9+2)+3), that is, first compute the infix binary operator on 9 and 2 and then compute the infix binary operator on the result and 3. What I get however is (9+2+3), all on the same level, which is really not all that helpful, after all I have now to decide the order of evaluation myself and yet it was defined to be left associative. Why am I forced to parenthesize myself? What am I missing?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You can just reduce each list recursively using the corresponding operator.

Comment: Of course I could, but I also could make a mistake doing this. Think about "1-2+3". I could take a chance at it, but I also could make a mistake, a mistake I couldn't possibly make if pyparsing was performing as one could expect